# Why must lagom services have two projects?

Tags: scala, lagom

I'm one of the stupid people that likes to know the why of things and not just the how. The lagom Documentation States "Every service contains at least two parts: an API project and an implementation project. (These are subprojects within the same build.)"

Does anyone know why? What is the purpose of this? What is the purpose of the API Project? What is the purpose of the Implementation project? What is the reason to do things this way?

Answer (score 4):

The API is the contract between you and clients. This means when you change it in any way and then you offer it back to those clients, you are saying that they must update the way they use it.

The implementation project does not affect clients such that they have to update their end, although when you do update it, it does not mean that it won't be a different service.

In other words, you can have the same API but different implementations and that does not affect the clients directly or; You can change the API in a breaking way such that clients won't even be able to use your service.

In Lagom, you can share the API because it is independent of your implementation and with little dependencies.

Comment: So basically the way lagom sets it up is so that I define the api file, then I define the implementation file. Then I am able to create multiple implementations and swap them out. I'm new to lagom so I will have to dig deeper, but this sounds pretty useful and awesome. I just like to make sure I understand things correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I found this link helpful it https://scalac.io/microservices-scala-lagom-reactive-platform/  under how is it built thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This way You don’t have to include implementation of every service you want to communicate with in service builds, so they are smaller.